# python cgi script is not executing in XAMPP

Tags: python, python-3.x, xampp

i am a beginner in python. I've installed python34, and xampp. I've changed the http.config file and added the .py extension in handler block. then i put my python script into xamp/bin-cgi and  set the first line of the python script as, "#!C:/Python34/python.exe". But when i opens the file through localhost/cgi-bin/test.py it doesn't showing anything only a blank screen, Below the content of the file.

```
#!C:/Python34/python.exe

print "Content-type: text/html"
print 
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>welcome cgi</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h1>first python page</h1>"
print "<p>heihei</p>"
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite the first line like this:

```
#!"C:\Python34\python.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Python 2.7 with your print statements. That is the first error. YOu are calling the Python 3.4 interpreters.

Also, you need to change your first line to

```
#!/Python34/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# enable debugging
```

Then, change your print statements to have parentheses

```
print("Content-type: text/html")
print() 
print("""<html>
         <head>
         <title>welcome cgi</title>
         </head>
         <body>
         <h1>first python page</h1>
         <p>heihei</p>
         </body>
        </html>""")
```

## ATTENTION:

If you notice, I changed up your code a bit and got rid of a bunch of print statements. Instead, I used what's called a `multiline string` (instead of writing `"blah"` I would do `"""blah"""`). For example if I did

```
print("asdasdasd
        asdasdasdasdasd")
```

This wouldn't work

But, if I changed it to

```
print("""asdasdasdasdasd
         asdasdasdasdasd""")
```

This would be a perfectly acceptable command. Every new line would be registered as a `"\n"` so really, the string we are printing out is `"asdasdasdasdasd\nasdasdasdasdasd"` where `\n` marks a new line